# Excel VBA copy & paste from one sheet and find duplicate after paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that copies a range of cells from one worksheet and then pastes them on a another worksheet, beneath row 26, based on the date.

I am trying to check for the existence of a part of text in row 5-25, prior to pasting the selection so i can highlight it a special color.

The below subroutine works fine to plot how I want, but when I try to call the function checkValue2 to FIND if the text exists, it runs once and then stops.

I am not sure if I have too many ranges identified or if the FIND activates the wrong sheet. Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub buildGantt()
clearGantt
Dim fundingDate As Range
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim sched As Worksheet
Dim startWeek As Date
Dim endWeek As Date
Dim Col_letter
Dim Col_letter2
Dim Col_letter3
Dim f As Range
Dim projRange As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim Modality As String
Dim modColor As Long

On Error Resume Next
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sourceBook = ThisWorkbook
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Oz")
Set sched = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")

'Determine last row of source from Oz which is the source worksheet
With sourceSheet
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'sorts sourcesheet based on Mech Start
sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

For x = 2 To SourceLastRow
    If sourceSheet.Range("L" & x).Value > (Now() - 21) Then 'L is install start
        Modality = sourceSheet.Range("A" & x).Value
        'MsgBox "what is in col A" & Modality
        Select Case sourceSheet.Range("A" & x).Value
            Case Is = "Holiday"
                modColor = RGB(183, 222, 232)
            Case Is = "PTO"
                modColor = RGB(255, 153, 204)
            Case Else
                modColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            End Select
        Modality = ""
        Set copyRange = sourceSheet.Range("G" & x & ":S" & x) 'the 12 columns to be copied
        Set f = sched.Cells.Range("3:3").Find(sourceSheet.Range("L" & x).Value) 'finds install start
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Col_letter = Split(Cells(1, f.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
            Col_letter2 = Split(Cells(1, (f.Column + 12)).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
            Col_letter3 = Split(Cells(1, (f.Column + 14)).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

            'paste in sched
            copyRange.Copy Destination:=sched.Range(Col_letter & (x + 40))
            Set projRange = sched.Cells.Range(Col_letter & (x + 40) & ":" & Col_letter2 & (x + 40))
            sched.Cells.Range(Col_letter3 & (x + 40)).Value = connectCells(projRange)
            sched.Range(Col_letter & (x + 40)).Interior.Color = modColor

            'this is the part that does not work properly
            SOrder = sched.Cells.Range(Col_letter & (x + 40)) 'used to identify what will be searched for
            columnL = Col_letter ' identifies what colum to search 
            MsgBox "returned value=" & checkValue2(SOrder, columnL) ' this works......but only allows it to run once
        Else
            '
        End If
        Set copyRange = Nothing
        Set f = Nothing
        Set Col_letter = Nothing
        Set Col_letter2 = Nothing
        Set Col_letter3 = Nothing
    Else
        '
    End If

Next x

sched.AutoFilterMode = False
'Cells.AutoFilter
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub


 Function checkValue2(str As String, ColumnLetter As String) As String
  Dim srchRng As Range
  Dim status As String
   'we only need to search in row 5 to 25
   'we are looking for the SOrder as part of the test contained in the cells above where it will be pasted
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")
        Set srchRng = .Range(ColumnLetter & "5:" & ColumnLetter & "25").Find(what:=str, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    lookat:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not srchRng Is Nothing Then
                        'MsgBox "SO found"
                        status = "green"
                    Else
                        'MsgBox "SO Not found"
                        status = "Red"
                    End If
    End With
    checkValue2 = status
End Function
```

Comment: Remove/comment out `On Error Resume Next` then come back and tell us what error message you're getting, if one :)

Comment: Still only runs through one record with no error then stalls. Missed the Dim of SOrder and columnL as string when I copied the code into here, but still only runs once.

Comment: what kind of data do you have in "Schedule" sheet row 3 and in "Oz" sheet column L

Comment: Have you stepped through checking the value of f? Maybe you only hit the right condition once to enter that part of the code

Comment: Sheet(schedule) row three has dates in it.

Comment: Sheet(OZ) Column L is the date match with Schedule to paste the range selected.

Comment: CheckValue2 returns a value no matter what. If I comment out the checkValue2 function all rows are properly pasted. When I enable the function, only one row pastes and gives a return checkvalue2. But the loop continues to run through all the records (checked by displaying a counter)

Comment: I finally took a different approach. The date check is performed separately in a different sub, then the Buildgantt sub is run. This will graphically display the conflicts and is awesome.  It is not perfect but it solves the problem.  Thank you for at least confirming that I was not crazy and it could be done.